# resteasy-spring module in jboss wildfly 8

Tags: deployment, jboss, resteasy, vfs, wildfly

I am having this problem with Wildfly 8 and resteasy-spring.jar (module). i am trying to deploy 2 wars on the same server, if i deploy 1 war it deploys fine, but whenever i add the second war it starts failing (and vice versa) with the following error:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."TaskandTeamManager.war".DEPENDENCIES: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."TaskandTeamManager.war".DEPENDENCIES: JBAS018733: Failed to process phase DEPENDENCIES of deployment "TaskandTeamManager.war"
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:166) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.0.Final.jar:1.2.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) [rt.jar:1.7.0_25]
Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: java.io.IOException: VFS000017: Filesystem already mounted at mount point ""/C:/servers/jboss/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-spring/main/bundled/resteasy-spring.jar""
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsSpringProcessor.deploy(JaxrsSpringProcessor.java:126)
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:159) [wildfly-server-8.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT.jar:8.0.0.Final-SNAPSHOT]
    ... 5 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: VFS000017: Filesystem already mounted at mount point ""/C:/servers/jboss/wildfly-8.0.0.Final/modules/system/layers/base/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-spring/main/bundled/resteasy-spring.jar""
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mount(VFS.java:127)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.doMount(VFS.java:336)
    at org.jboss.vfs.VFS.mountZip(VFS.java:360)
    at org.jboss.as.jaxrs.deployment.JaxrsSpringProcessor.deploy(JaxrsSpringProcessor.java:119)
    ... 6 more
```

I already tried adding a dependencies in jboss-deployment-structure (META-INF), but i get the same error, both projects are using rest-easy and jackson dependencies.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a bug. For now if you add the context param org.jboss.as.jaxrs.disableSpringIntegration=true to your application it should work around it.

Comment: There is already a fix pending merge https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/pull/5870 that will be part of WildFly 8.0.0.Final

Comment: this worked for now, thanks alot Stuart!, waiting for the fix to be published as a Nightbuild.